# can't see Azure Function in Function app UI from web portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy, azure-functions-core-tools

I can't see function listed under function app. So ultimately can't see monitor or logs as well.

- Can upload from VS
- Can logon to appservice editor and see function listed there.

If I try to create new function or access excising  it keep loading.

Have tried in different Chrome and IE.

Not getting what is missing, please help.

[Accessing Function keep loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enWLi.png)
 [Creating new function keep loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQyxS.png)

Comment: We're looking into this, but need some additional information from you. Would you mind e-mailing me directly at katy.shimizu@microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your **good internet connection**. It may cause timeout issue.

**Large, long-running functions can cause unexpected timeout issues.**

> A function can become large due to many Node.js dependencies. 
>   Importing dependencies can also cause increased load times that result in unexpected timeouts. 
>   Dependencies are loaded both explicitly and implicitly. 
>   A single module loaded by your code may load its own additional modules.

Also, you could use click **View->Server Explorer** in Visual Studio to open your resource group and find your azure function.

In it, it contains all the function your created and the Log Files. It almost like Azure function on portal, so if you still have this problem, you could use it instead.

[image]

Comment: but how I get live log messages ? it is not easy to test without it. any other way possible please, can I somehow get live log messages locally or in VS  ?

Comment: @hussmon, you also could [see invocation log in KUDU](http://markheath.net/post/three-ways-view-error-logs-azure-functions). You get to that by navigating to `https://myfunctionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net`. Then you need to select Tools | WebJobs dashboard and then choose Functions.